# Angular Post json to .net core web api is null

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to post some JSON to a web api .net core but for some reason this is always null no matter what i have tried see code below.

this is my .net core web api code

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/v1/Issues")]
    [Authorize]
    [EnableCors("AllowCors")]
    public class IssuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostIssues([FromBody] string issue)
        {
          //some code to desirialize
        }
    }
```

and this is how i am trying to post via angular (note that the appropriate services are loaded)

```
    public addIssue(issue) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    this.authService.getToken().toPromise().then( t => {
      headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${t.toString()}`);
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/v1/issues`, issue, {
        headers: headers
      }).toPromise()
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.json());
        });
    });
  }
```

i have tried changing the post to

```
this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/v1/issues`, JSON.stringify(issue))
```

and even

```
this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/v1/issues`, {'issue', JSON.stringify(issue)})
```

but nothing seems to work anyone has any idea why this is happening?
To clarify the `string issue` received on the API is what is always null.
Here is the successfull response of when i reaches the server you can see the request payload is not null but reaches the web api as null
[image]

**UPDATE 1 Explanation required if possible**
Alright i wanted to do a little experiment the same code worked fine for a 4.5 framework instead of a .net core however what i tried to do for .net core and worked was create a class called foo see below

```
public class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Json { get; set; }
    }
```

And modify my Controller to accept this object

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostIssues([FromBody] Foo issue)
    {
       Debug.Write(issue);
       return Ok(issue);
    }
```

As well as my Angular project to pass a similar format body

```
public addIssue(issue) {
const headers = new Headers();
this.authService.getToken().toPromise().then( t => {

  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${t.toString()}`);
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/v1/issues`, {'name' : 'name', 'json': JSON.stringify(issue)}, {
    headers: headers,
    withCredentials: true
  }).toPromise()
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.json());
    });
});
```

}

And this manages to pass successfully and bind to the controller 
[image]

Why is this Ok but not able to pass a Json directly? and why does my original code works on 4.5 framework but not on .net core?

Comment: What are you returning in `PostIssues()`? What's the value of `issue` in your JS?

Comment: I am returning Ok(desieralized issue) but i dont see why that would be an issue the issue is that the json i post is received as null on the api

Comment: Ah okay - I thought you meant `res.json()` was null. What does your client request look like (from Fiddler or dev tools)?

Comment: I have posted the client request as per your request

Comment: I believe your request body needs an `issue` attribute. Have you tried adding it to the request body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to answer all your questions.

> string issue received on the API  is always null

Passing a JSON to this will always get you a null because you are trying to bind to a primitive data type. To fix this you have two options

**Bind to a model ( viewmodel )**

When your parameter is a class, asp will bind this class to the json data you passed that's why you were able to get the `name` data.
Based on your update, you might probably go this route.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

Now you might be wondering why would you create a class just to be used on your api when the parameter is just a string?! If you want to use just the `string` in your api then you can do this

**Pass the data using `FormData`**

You need to change your api like this

```
 public IActionResult PostIssues(string issue){..}
```

You don't need to specify  the `[FromBody]` here.

In your client-side,

```
 public addIssue(issue) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    this.authService.getToken().toPromise().then( t => {
      headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${t.toString()}`);
     // new code here
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('issue',issue); //you need to specify the parameter name here.
      this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/v1/issues`, formData, {
        headers: headers
      }).toPromise()
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.json());
        });
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense and covers me will mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

since it is a single string you can pass it in the url

```
${this.baseUrl}/v1/issues?issue=yourVarIssue
```

Comment: I would like to avoid that as there might be a a couple long strings in there and from past experience that can cause plenty of issues if there length gets over a certain size.

Comment: based on a similar question, I think you have to add this headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719017/angular-post-json-to-net-core-web-api-is-null/45719221?noredirect=1#comment78396673_45719221

Comment: If i do this i get a 415 error if i leave it as application/json it reaches the api but null